# time_amount says it is undefined even tho there are 2 arguments

Tags: discord.js, arguments

when i execute the command with 2 agrumments it then sends in the channel "member gas been timed out for undefined seconds"

example command: !timeout @user 10

```
    if (command === 'timeout'){
       let { member, time_amount} = args
                if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide a amount of time or a member, ${message.author}!`);
        } else { 
            if(args.length = 0){
                message.channel.send(`there are only ${args.length} argument please add the right arguments`)
            }
            else{
                if(args.length = 1){
          
             console.log(time_amount)
            if(isNaN(time_amount)){
                if (message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'owner')){ 
            const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(argument[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find( x => x.user.username.toLocaleLowerCase() === argument.slice(0).join(" " || x.user.username === argument[0]));
            member.timeout()
            message.channel.send(`member has been timed out for `+ time_amount + ` seconds`)
            setTimeout(function(){message.channel.send('the user <@' + member.id + '> is not in timeout anymore.')}, time_amount)
        }
        else{
       message.channel.send('you dont have the right promitions <@' + message.author.id + '>.')
        }
            }
            else{
                message.channel.send(`time amount is not a number, <@${message.author.id}>`)
        }
                }
                else{
                    message.channel.send(`there are to many agruments please add the right arguments`)
                }

     }
 
    }

        
    
        
    }
```

i want that time_amount stores the second argument so could somebody help me

Comment: this is a screenschot of me using the command ---> https://imgur.com/a/OBxrgkO

Comment: Well, you check `if(isNaN(time_amount))`. If it's `undefined` you execute the block containing ```message.channel.send(`member has been timed out for `+ time_amount + ` seconds`)```, so your code works as expected.